# Apache 2.4: Require IP does not work as expected

Tags: apache-2.4

I got the following configuration in my apache2.4 web server:

```
<FilesMatch "(^\.|wp-config\.php|xmlrpc\.php|(?<!robots)\.txt|(liesmich|readme)\.*)"> 
Require ip 216.151.209.64 216.151.209.127 66.135.48.128 66.135.48.255 69.174.248.128 69.174.248.255 76.74.255.0 76.74.255.127 216.151.210.0 216.151.210.127 76.74.248.128 76.74.248.255 76.74.254.0 76.74.254.127 207.198.112.0 207.198.113.255 207.198.101.0 207.198.101.127 198.181.116.0 198.181.119.255 192.0.64.0 192.0.127.255 66.155.8.0 66.155.11.255 66.155.38.0 66.155.38.255 72.233.119.192 72.233.119.255 209.15.21.0 209.15.21.255
</FilesMatch>
```

Well, if I call `example.com/xmlrpc.php` from a valid IP (e.g. `216.151.209.64`), I'm still getting `401`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Typically your server log contains a hint as to why access was denied. Since you only include part of your configuration there may also be other [applicable sections of your configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging) or a `.htaccess` file in the path. The regex appears OK though.

Answer (score 2):

1. The robots rules is wrong, as any file .txt will match this regexp, even robots.txt.

So you need to change `(?<!robots)\.txt` by `(!robots\.txt)`

2. `401` error mean you are not logged in. Here `Require ip` should trigger `403` error. That mean, to get access to those files, you need to be logged AND use an ip from the list.